# Real-time streaming of an MP4 file

Tags: php, flash, mp4, live-streaming

Is it possible to play the video (mp4) in real time using some flash player? What I mean by in real-time is that player would receive data on the fly, not from alredy saved file but e.g. php script (which sends appropriate content-type header) THAT IS DOWNLOADING AND 'ECHO-ing' THE FILE AT THE TIME PLAYER PLAYS IT - like e.g. some kind of live stream.

Answer (score 1):

[JW Player](http://www.longtailvideo.com/players/) can play streaming video, and LongTail Video also has some good (practical) info on streaming in general:

http://www.longtailvideo.com/support/search/google_cse_adv/streaming

**Edit**: Maybe I didn't read the question quite as well as i ought to before I answered, but here is info on so called pseudo streaming that can be implemented in PHP:

http://www.longtailvideo.com/support/jw-player/jw-player-for-flash-v5/12534/video-delivery-http-pseudo-streaming

Answer (score 1):

For instant playback using flash, you need to format your mp4 file to have the moov header box at the front of the file for playback to start right away. This can be done by the qt-faststart utility.

To allow for seeking in the file using flash (to a portion of the file not downloaded) you need to utilize pseudo streaming. (Since flash has disabled the partial bytes header). This needs to be implemented on the server side: http://h264.code-shop.com/trac as well as the flash side (both jwplayer and flowplayer supports this approach, and sends ?start=123 param on seek)

The other option is to use the html5  tag (but mp4 is only supported in a few browsers) - then you do not need the pseudostreaming backend.

Answer (score -1):

You can use VLC media player from:

http://www.videolan.org/vlc/

After you successfully installed it, click on the menu Media->Open Network Stream and fill in the URL for the video.

Comment: I was hoping for a web-based solution, with use of e.g. something like flowplayer. Using VLC is the only way?

Comment: I misunderstood your question. I thought you wanted a desktop solution. Not sure if flowplayer got that feature, but there's a commercial solution **Moyea Web Player** @ http://www.playerdiy.com